# HOSTNAME environment variable on Linux

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

On my Linux box (Gentoo Linux 2.6.31 to be specific) I have noticed that the HOSTNAME environment variable is available in my shell, but not in scripts. For example,

```
$ echo $HOSTNAME
```

returns

```
xxxxxxxx.com,
```

but

```
$ ruby -e 'puts ENV["HOSTNAME"]'
```

returns

```
nil
```

On the other hand, the USER environment variable, for instance, is available both in the shell and in scripts.

I have noticed that USER appears in the list of environment variables that appears when I type

```
export
```

i.e.,

```
declare -x USER="infogrind"
```

but HOSTNAME doesn't. I suspect the issue has something to do with that.

My questions: 1) how can I make HOSTNAME available in scripts, and 2) for my better understanding, where is this variable initially set, and why is it not "exported"?

Answer (score 27):

`$HOSTNAME` is a Bash variable that's set automatically (rather than in a startup file). Ruby probably runs `sh` for its shell and it doesn't include that variable. There's no reason you can't export it yourself.

```
bash$ echo $HOSTNAME
foobar
bash$ sh -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'

bash$ export HOSTNAME
bash$ sh -c 'echo $HOSTNAME'
foobar
```

You could add the export command to one of your startup files, such as `~/.bashrc`.

In Ruby (irb shown):

```
>> require 'socket'
=> true
>> Socket.gethostname
=> "bazinga"
```

Comment: It is usually better to use `gethostname()` because of this.

Comment: The posix standard enumerates the environment variables you should expect on a posix-compliant systems, and HOSTNAME is not in the list: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, `HOSTNAME` is a Bash variable but it's not a Bash *environment* variable (i. e. it's not passed in *environment* to child processes). One can check this by looking at `env` output:

```bash
/tmp$ echo $BASH_VERSION
5.2.21(1)-release
/tmp$ echo $HOSTNAME
wheleph-mbp.local
/tmp$ env | grep HOSTNAME
/tmp$
```

`ENV["HOSTNAME"]` reads *environment* passed to Ruby interpreter, hence it cannot find `HOSTNAME` there.